# minimax function giving me false results

Tags: java, tic-tac-toe, minimax

I've been trying to write a miniMax algorithm for an "evolved" tic-tac-toe(9x9). However, it seems that whenever I call this algorithm it crashes on the mini part. The getAvailableMoves function assigns each and every move a "score". The score gets higher if it brings the 1st player an advantage. It seems to somewhat work if I make the first move, however, if I am Mini(the 2nd one to make a move) it simply gets the first available move, ALWAYS. I've been trying to figure out what I'm doing wrong, but I can't spot the problem. Anyone got any ideas?

```
public Move mini( Field field, int depth, int player )
    {
        if( depth == 0 || field.isFull() )
        {
            ArrayList<Move> moves = field.getAvailableMoves(-player);
            if( moves.isEmpty() ) return null;
            int miniProfit = moves.get(0).getBenefit(), index = 0;
            for( int i = 1 ; i < moves.size() ; i++ )
            {
                if( miniProfit < moves.get(i).getBenefit() )
                {
                    miniProfit = moves.get(i).getBenefit();
                    index = i;
                }
            }
            moves.get(index).benefit = - moves.get(index).benefit;
            return moves.get(index);
        }
        ArrayList<Move> moves = field.getAvailableMoves(player);
        Move miniMove = new Move();
        miniMove.benefit = Move.Inf;
        for( Move move : moves )
        {
            field.applyMove(move, player);
            Move move2 = maxi( field, depth - 1, -player );
            if( move2 == null ) continue;
            int mini = move2.getBenefit();
            if( mini <= miniMove.benefit )
            {
                miniMove = move;
            }
            field.unapplyMove(move, player);    
        }
        return miniMove;
    }

    public Move maxi( Field field, int depth, int player )
    {
        if( depth == 0 || field.isFull() )
        {
            ArrayList<Move> moves = field.getAvailableMoves(player);
            if( moves.isEmpty() ) return null;
            int maxiProfit = moves.get(0).getBenefit(), index = 0;
            for( int i = 1 ; i < moves.size() ; i++ )
            {
                if( maxiProfit < moves.get(i).getBenefit() )
                {
                    maxiProfit = moves.get(i).getBenefit();
                    index = i;
                }
            }
            return moves.get(index);
        }
        ArrayList<Move> moves = field.getAvailableMoves(player);
        Move maxiMove = new Move();
        maxiMove.benefit = 0 - Move.Inf;
        for( Move move : moves )
        {
            field.applyMove(move, player);
            Move move2 = mini( field, depth - 1 , -player );
            if( move2 == null ) continue;
            int maxi = move2.getBenefit();
            if( maxi >= maxiMove.benefit )
            {
                maxiMove = move;
            }
            field.unapplyMove(move, player);    
        }
        return maxiMove;
    }

    public Move makeTurn(Field field) {
            int depth = 5;
            if( myId == 1 )
            {
                return maxi(field, depth, 1);
            }
            else
            {
                return mini(field, depth, -1);
            }
        }
```

Comment: "it crashes on the mini part" - crash like "throws exception" or crash like "does not deliver expected result"? What is your input when you test?

Comment: Does not deliver the expected result (it always evaluates to the first move

Comment: Incomplete. The crucial part is getAvailableMoves(), how does it assign for -player ?